# Cakephp query with big database and pagination

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp and Mysql to develop a shop System where a register all the products I sell, the system was working fine till I started to make some tests, I have introduced more than 30.000 registers of products and from there on, I can't search for my products cause I'm having this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)`

From my research if found that this is related to memory and I could increase the memory but also I have realized that these would be a momentum solution.
I have seen that the function called in the controller **products** is this:

```
public function search() {
    $this->Product->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('products', $this->paginate());
    $products = $this->Product->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('products'));
}
```

and from this I see that this could be the problem cause it's fetching all the products.

So the help I need is how to improve this, what would be the best approach for this. On my research one of the solution I was expecting to get is probably to have this query but fetching like 10 by time I don't know if it's possible.

Thanks in Advance.
PS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the last two lines.

You're doing the paginated call, which is what you want, but then throwing it away and fetching ALL the records.  Which is pretty expensive when you have lots of data.

```
public function search() {
    $this->Product->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('products', $this->paginate());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, This is the solution but it's not complete, it's only showing me 20 records limited by 10

Comment: That's right.  You need to add the pagination to your view as well: echo $this->Paginator->numbers();

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CakePHP version 2 than this is the right way to use paginator, you can also limit the data per page with something else like 10, 20, 30 etc. so that all data can't be load at once.

```
public function search() {
 $this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'recursive' => 0
 );
 $products = $this->Paginator->paginate('Product');
 $this->set(compact('products'));
}
```